# Whatsapp deep link send a message to multiple specified phone numbers

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, whatsapp, universal-link

I have a list of phone numbers and a message string. I want to be able to send the message to all the numbers at once. I am using React Native's Linking module and deep links to do this.

I have tried various urls but none of them work.

`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=91xxxxxxxxx&text=hi` works but only for a single number.

`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?text=hi&phone=91xxxx&phone=91yyyy` is valid but it only considers the last number.

None of `&phone=91xxx,91yyyy`, `&phone=91xxxx;91yyyy`, `&phone=91xxxx:91yyyy`, `&phone=[91xxxx,91yyyy]` are even valid.

Edit: If I leave out the `&phone=` key, then it opens the share sheet and lets me choose the contacts there. But that is not what I want. I want the contacts in the list to be pre-selected already, like it does with the single number case.